# Missing search options in Atom "Find in Project" panel

Tags: atom-editor

When I bring up the "Search in Files" panel in Atom I cannot see the search option that would let me restrict the search to "Whole Word".

[image: Search in Files]

I can only see it when I do "Search in Buffer".

[image: Search in Buffer]

Is there a tick box I am not checking somewhere?

I am using Atom 1.0 on Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is currently missing from Atom 1.0. See the following issues for more details:

- https://github.com/atom/find-and-replace/issues/339
- https://github.com/atom/find-and-replace/pull/435

As described in the second link, the functionality was added and merged into the Atom codebase on July 9th, 2015, which means that it will likely appear in one of the next (post-1.0) versions.

The new feature is included in v0.175.0 of the `find-and-replace` core package. Atom v1.0.2 (the current version at the time of writing) still ships with v0.174.2 of this package.

Stay tuned, it should be available shortly.

Comment: Thanks for the update. It didn't cross my mind to check the issues list on GitHub. I'll think about it next time.